# NavigationDrawer event handler method is called on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with a NavigationDrawer (don't know it it matters or not). When I click an item on the NavigationDrawer, a fragment is added to the main activity using **newInstance()** factory method. The idea is simple as that.

When the program runs:

```
Inside MainActivity()
```

And I click an item on the NavigationDrawer:

```
Inside MyFragment.newInstance() // It is me who calls it.
Inside MyFragment() // This is called inside newInstance(). Nothing out of my expectation.
```

Then, I rotate the screen:

```
Inside MainActivity() // FragmentManager re-creates the activity and the fragment for a new screen layout.
Inside MyFragment() // My saved data in Bundle persists.
Inside MyFragment.newInstance() // ???
Inside MyFragment() // Now that my saved data in Bundle object is lost, because it is no longer the old fragment.
```

What is the cause of this strange behavior? Who is responsible for calling newInstance() when I rotate the screen?

Edit: The code for NavigationDrawer was default generated by Android Studio.

```
// Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: check out your onConfigurationChanged method ...

Comment: I have not implemented it yet. It is still the default one inherited from Activity.

Comment: Without code we can only guess. *What is the cause of this strange behavior?* - most likely you don't take in consideration the configuration change and you call again the listener from the navigation drawer.

Comment: Almost all the code is default generated so I was lazy to copy paste them all here. You are right -- the **onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int)** was called when the screen was rotated. Any suggestion to prevent that?

Comment: If that call happens in the `onCreate` callback then check if the `Bundle` passed in is not `null`. If it isn't null then you're dealing with a configuration change in which case you don't need to call that method again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Android Studio default generated code was the culprit here. Thanks Luksprog for the suggestion and his guessing talent. :D

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}
```

The cause of the problem is the line **selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);**, which is called every time the NavigationDrawer is created, including the case of screen rotating.